# Qradar directory access

Tags: python, linux, directory, linux-kernel, qradar

I want to access the folder /store/ariel/events/payloads/ in the Qradar directories from the App editor. I am trying the os.path.exists however it returns false however, the folder exists as well as the path is located if I run the script in the linux kernel of the Qradar. I would really appreciate if anyone can guide me on how to access the directories from the Qradar App Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it, unfortunately.
In QRadar, Apps can only interact with the rest of the deployment via API calls.

The [App Framework guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS42VS_SHR/com.ibm.appfw.doc/b_qradar_appframework_devguide.pdf?origURL=SS42VS_7.3.3/com.ibm.appfw.doc/b_qradar_appframework_devguide.pdf) can provide some more details about what's available to App developers.